# State array value not getting set in render in react native

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to render few checkboxes based on an array data that I get from the server. This is how I've declared my state variable

```
 this.state = {
           isLoading: true,
           checkBoxes: []
        };

//This is how I set value in componentDidMount

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Data from JSON = " + JSON.stringify(this.props.dataSource[GLOBAL.JSONKEYS.OPTIONS]));

this.setState({
        checkBoxes: JSON.stringify(this.props.dataSource[GLOBAL.JSONKEYS.OPTIONS]),
        isLoading: false
      });
}


 render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activityStyle}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }

    console.log("checkboxArray in render = " + this.state.checkBoxes);

   ... code to render view

}
```

Below is the resulting log on console

> Data from JSON =
>   [{"id":1,"value":"Category1","isChecked":false},{"id":2,"value":"Category2","isChecked":false},{"id":3,"value":"Category3","isChecked":false},{"id":4,"value":"Other","isChecked":false}]
>
> checkboxArray in render =

As you can see that eventhough I do get the data in componentDidMount, the checkboxArray in render method still seems to be null. Looks like its value is not getting set. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get isChecked value from data and collect them and set to state them in your componentDidMount.

```
    const checkBoxes = [];
    const data = this.props.dataSource[GLOBAL.JSONKEYS.OPTIONS];
    data.map((item) => {
        checkBoxes.push(item.isChecked);
    });

    this.setState({
        checkBoxes,
        isLoading: false
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I'm still getting blank value in render, also in my checkBox I need the whole JSON data instead of just item.

Comment: Can you share your all class or demo? Maybe another code set checkBoxes's state to null?

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Looks like I didn't need that JSON.stringify option to get the checkboxArray value, didn't noticed that earlier. And I modified your code a little bit to push in whole item and it worked.